# Sentence maker with thesaurus

Tags: strings, ruby, regex, combinatorics

I'm teaching myself Ruby by rewriting PHP solutions, such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31487650/1338292). The program should match words in a sentence with a dictionary of synonyms and then make combinations with them.

```
dict = {
    'hello' => ['hey', 'what\'s up'],
    'name' => ['nomenclature', 'epithet']
}

str = 'hello, my name is'

class SentenceMaker
    def initialize str, dict
        @thesaurus = []
        @template = str.gsub(/\w+/) {|match|
            if (dict[match])
                @thesaurus.push dict[match]
                '%%%d$s' % @thesaurus.length
            else
                match
            end
        }
    end

    def each
        @thesaurus.first.product(*@thesaurus.slice(1..-1)).each {|repl|
            yield @template % repl
        }
    end
end

SentenceMaker.new(str, dict).each {|sentence|
    puts sentence
}
```

Example output

```
hey, my nomenclature is
hey, my epithet is
what's up, my nomenclature is
what's up, my epithet is
```

Does this make enough use of the language expressions, or did I miss a few things?

Answer (score 5):

Overall, it's pretty good. My comments are:

- Use do/end for multiline blocks.
- Typical Ruby style is a 2-space indent.
- I think `@thesaurus.drop(1)` looks a bit better than `@thesaurus.slice(1..-1)`
- `match` is not a good local variable name, `word` is more descriptive
- Template is too complicated: you can just use multiple `%s` placeholders with an array of Strings.

I'm not commenting too much on the algorithm, since you weren't asking, but it seems a bit complicated. I'd be tempted to try simplifying it a bit.

Here's your code with the above changes applied:

```
dict = {
  'hello' => ['hey', 'what\'s up'],
  'name' => ['nomenclature', 'epithet'],
}

str = 'hello, my name is'

class SentenceMaker
  def initialize str, dict
    @thesaurus = []
    @template = str.gsub(/\w+/) do |word|
      if (dict[word])
        @thesaurus.push dict[word]
        '%s'
      else
        word
      end
    end
  end

  def each
    @thesaurus.first.product(*@thesaurus.drop(1)).each do |repl|
      yield @template % repl
    end
  end
end

SentenceMaker.new(str, dict).each {|sentence|
  puts sentence
}
```

Comment: Good point about the template; it was a left-over artefact from the previous simplification round :) out of curiosity, what's better about `do .. end` versus braces?

Comment: Also, I would be interested to see what you would do to the algorithm :)

Comment: @Jack It is just a convention, curly braces for single lines, `do end` for multilines blocks.

Comment: I would also add to use double quotes when your string has a single quote in it to avoid needing to escape the apostrophe/single quote.  Also I would organize the class at the top, the running code at the bottom.  (the local variable assignments right above the SentenceMaker.new line.)  Keeps things organized in a more logical way, rather than splitting what is running with a class definition in the middle.